# d3js: How to pass button id to onclick callback function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback

I understand that callback functions have access to bound data and their indices, but how would you pass an additional parameter to the callback function?

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="viz">
        <button id="one"> One </button>
        <button id="two"> Two </button>
        <button id="three"> Three </button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    // setup buttons
    d3.select("#one").on("click", clickPrint("one"));
    d3.select("#two").on("click", clickPrint("two"));
    d3.select("#three").on("click", clickPrint("three"));

    // callback function
    function clickPrint(arg) {
        console.log("You clicked on button:" + arg);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Essentially, I'd like the buttons to all access the same callback function, but for that function to know which button called it. I know that normally the callback function would not have parens, i.e. `d3.select("#one").on("click", clickPrint);`, but this was my attempt at passing a button-specific parameter. I understand that I don't have any data bound (I do in what I'm actually working on) - if that is somehow related, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to know what button was clicked, you can find `id` from button like this,, hope that's what you need..

```js
    // setup buttons
    d3.select("#one").on("click", clickPrint);
    d3.select("#two").on("click", clickPrint);
    d3.select("#three").on("click", clickPrint);

    // callback function
    function clickPrint() {
        console.log( this.id );
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

    <div id="viz">
        <button id="one"> One </button>
        <button id="two"> Two </button>
        <button id="three"> Three </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ah, `this` gets me again. Thank you. For bonus points, do you know how I could pass an actual argument to the callback function, i.e. not just the id?